# Qt: different scenario if loading dll failed

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dll

I believe task I am trying to accomplish is fairly easy, but I have still managed to run into a problem, thus some help is appreciated.

I have got a base class (in a header and a source file), which I am subclassing two times as part of my program, lets call it `WorkerBase`. One of subclasses `WorkerA` is fairly trivial, whilst the other, `WorkerB`, depends on third-party libraries that depend on the hardware which program is running on. If hardware is unsuitable or those libraries are missing, using that subclass results in a fail. In this case, I would like to use `WorkerA`.

So, basically, how do I detect library loading failure? Now main program just wouldn't start if library is missing.

I am using Qt and the program is going to be Windows-only. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the simplest solution would be to move `Woker`'s to plugins.

You can load plugin with `QPluginLoader` dynamically during run-time.

Then, while `WorkerB` would be statically linked to 3rd party lib, if required dependencies for `WorkerB` would not be satisfied, `WorkerB` plugin will simply fail to load, you would catch that with `QPluginLoader` and load `WorkerA` plugin instead.

The other way is to reinvent <s>the wheel</s> your own plugin system using `QLibrary` (and `QPluginLoader` as a reference realization).

Answer (score 0):

Possibly that helps

http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qlibrary.html

```
bool QLibrary::load ()
```

*Loads the library and returns true if the library was loaded successfully; otherwise returns false. Since resolve() always calls this function before resolving any symbols it is not necessary to call it explicitly. In some situations you might want the library loaded in advance, in which case you would use this function.*

Comment: Tried it, did not help. Program links with the library (.a) at compile time and requires .dll at runtime. If I do not link it, I get many 'undefined reference' errors. Perhaps, I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Oh it links at compile time. You can try to test it and catch any exceptions.

Comment: Or I could somehow get rid of the compile time linking. But how do I use `WorkerB` then?

Comment: About the exceptions: how do I get the "dll not found" or smth like that exception in Qt?

Comment: If dll is not found at compile time, you' do not get runtime errors and exceptions of course,  I just can to guess what kind of errors you get.

Comment: There are no exceptions thrown when a DLL can't be loaded at runtime, that is handled in the process linker and gives an error, which then immediately unloads or cancels loading of the DLL. With dynamic linking, this will cause all modules relying on the failed module to also fail; with runtime linking you can handle the error, but you can't import any symbols (they must be manually loaded).